# How do you reference the meta and arrow key combinations in emacs init.el?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I am trying to override Meta + left / right arrow keys in my emacs config and cannot figure out how to refer to the key sequence.

If I interact with Emacs directly I can type
"M-x, global-set-key, M-, next-buffer", and it works fine. But I can't figure out how to type this into my init.el file. These are some things that I have tried:

```
(global-set-key "\M right" 'next-buffer)
(global-set-key "\M <right>" 'next-buffer)
(global-set-key [\M right] 'next-buffer)
(global-set-key [M right] 'next-buffer)
(global-set-key [M-right] 'next-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd M-<right>) 'next-buffer)
(global-set-key [M (kbd <right>)] 'next-buffer)
```

etc.

More Info:

OK, this does work natively: `(global-set-key [M-right] 'next-buffer)` (thank you) - it's not working on iTerm2 in a VM (minor detail :)
And for that environment: `M-x describe-key` does not open help but in `*Messages*` prints: `ESC <right> (translated from ESC M-[ C) is undefined`

And that's why I was confused and was not able to just paste that into kbd.
And that's why I don't think it is being trumped by another mode.

Comment: `(global-set-key [M-right] 'next-buffer)` works for me, so you probably have a major-mode or minor-mode that is trumping (taking precedence) over the global setting.  Type `M-x describe-key` and then `M-right` and update your question or post a comment with the result.  Also, provide what major-mode you are running and minor-modes that are active.  You can type `M-x describe-mode` to find out all of that information.

Comment: Re: edit, why do you say you were not able to use either  `(kbd "ESC <right>")` or `(kbd "ESC M-[ C")` ?

Comment: "why do you say..." sounds like `M-x doctor`

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to specify a key binding is always to use **`kbd`**.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<M-right>") 'next-buffer)
```

`kbd` takes as argument an external key description, i.e., what Emacs tells you when you use `C-h k`.

Use `C-h k`, press and hold the Meta (e.g. Alt) key, and hit the right arrow key. Buffer `*Help*` tells you that this key sequence is written `"<M-right>"`.  So that's what you pass to `kbd`.

Comment: That is not the case in my emacs 24.3.1. When I do the above, for metakey + up arrow, the help buffer says I pressed `<s-up>`, but the global-set-key does not work with anything else other than `[s-up]`.

Comment: @Sonny: Are you saying that you cannot do `(global-set-key (kbd "<s-up>") 'next-buffer)`? (And do you mean `S-up` instead of `s-up`?) And it seems odd that your "metakey" acts as a super key (or as a Shift key). Is that what you see when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)?

Comment: yes. I tried `emacs -Q` and same thing. I meant `s-up`, BTW. I use emacs 24.3.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 on x86_64, though I am not sure if that is pertinent.

Comment: OK. Sounds like a bug that `[s-up]` works and help tells you the binding is `<s-up>` but the latter doesn't work (with `kbd`). You might want to do `M-x report-emacs-bug` - dunno.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: `(global-set-key (kbd "ESC <right>") 'next-buffer)`

Thanks - I needed the combination of `kbd` and what to pass it.